# How do you get the Translated Label of a Global Picklist in Apex Code?

Tags: rest, mobile, salesforce, apex-code, multilingual

I have a mobile app that is using REST to communicate with Salesforce.  The Application is multi-language and so is sending back a translation of what the picklist value is, which is identical to what we are setting the translated label to in Salesforce, But when I do a .getLabel() on the picklist value (when logged in as the user) It is still only returning the English Version of the Label.  So how do I get the Translated Version of the Label?

```
private static String statusMapper(String value){
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'value = ' + value);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'UserInfo.getLanguage(); = ' + UserInfo.getLanguage());
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusOptions = Dealer_Inventory_Asset__c.Status__c.getDescribe();
    Map<String, String> labelToValueMap = new Map<String, String>();

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : statusOptions.getPicklistValues()){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'p.getLabel() = ' + p.getLabel());
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'p.getValue() = ' + p.getValue());
        labelToValueMap.put(p.getLabel(), p.getValue());
    }

    if(labelToValueMap.containsKey(value)){
        return labelToValueMap.get(value);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Debug Log Sample:

```
18:07:02.0 (165065101)|USER_DEBUG|[413]|ERROR|value = N- No Scan Required fr
18:07:02.0 (165065101)|USER_DEBUG|[414]|ERROR|UserInfo.getLanguage(); = fr
18:07:02.0 (165998322)|USER_DEBUG|[420]|ERROR|p.getLabel() = N- No Scan Required
18:07:02.0 (166101692)|USER_DEBUG|[421]|ERROR|p.getValue() = N- No Scan Required
18:07:02.0 (166190471)|USER_DEBUG|[420]|ERROR|p.getLabel() = S- Scan still needed
18:07:02.0 (166233031)|USER_DEBUG|[421]|ERROR|p.getValue() = S- Scan still needed
```

Sample of the Translations Table:

[image: Translation Table]

I feel like there is some fundamental thing I am missing,  I can get around it by creating a translation table,  but I feel like this should work.

Answer (score -1):

That apex code works as intended, the API will return the display name for the picklist value - optionally translated according to user locale.

So, to verify everything is in place a check list could be:
- proper translations are provided for locales
- executing user has correct locale that matches the one required by mobile app

API doc is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm